# How can a QUBO matrix with many identical, non-zero off-diagonal terms be made sparse?

Tags: d-wave, annealing, qubo, embedding

I am with a QUBO matrix where entire off-diagonal sections are with the same value, which is the same between sections. Consider the following example (much smaller than those I am actually working with):

$$
H=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \gamma & \gamma & \gamma & 5 & 3 & 3 & 2 \\
- & 1 & \gamma & \gamma & 4 & 2 & 3 & -4 \\
- & - & 1 & \gamma & -5 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
- & - & - & 1 & -3 & 3 & -9 & 2 \\
- & - & - & - & 2 & \gamma & \gamma & \gamma \\
- & - & - & - & - & 2 & \gamma & \gamma \\
- & - & - & - & - & - & 2 & \gamma \\
- & - & - & - & - & - & - & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Here, $\gamma$ is non-zero, which means that the graph represented by this QUBO problem is fully-connected. Embedding a fully-connected graph on the D-Wave QPU of course requires qubit chaining to carry out such problems.

I am wondering if it is possible to apply a transformation to this QUBO in such a way that the $\gamma$ terms go to zero while preserving the energy landscape. This way, less couplings are present, leading to a sparser graph and an embedding that requires less qubit chaining.

In my naivety, it seems that I should be able to subtract $\gamma J$ from $H$, where $J$ is the matrix of ones, to accomplish this, as this is akin to a constant offset to a function, which doesn't change the overall shape of that function. Is this correct?